# Type aliases for __le__ and __ge__

Tags: python, python-typing

I would want to write:

```
class MyClass:
    def __le__(self, other:MyClass):
        ...
    def __ge__(self, other:MyClass):
        ...
    ...
```

Unfortunately, Python throws an error because MyClass isn't yet initialized. Is there another way to specify the type alias here?

Comment: If memory serves there is a way to use the name as a string now to specifically solve this problem.

Comment: The _specific error_ is much more useful for making a question discoverable than _"an error"_, and searching for it would have found the dupe.